# Different Hidden Fields Gets Same Value In Asp.net C# Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper, hidden-field

I have an action which looks like this:

```
public ActionResult NewPicture(int id)
{
    var response = service.Get(id);
    if (!response.Succeed)
       return Error(response.MainError.ErrorType);
    return ManagementView("/Gallery/EditPicture.cshtml", new PictureSaveViewModel() { Id = 0, GalleryId = id });
}
```

In the `PictureSaveViewModel` the `GalleryId` refers to parent gallery and the `Id` is the picture's Id. Because it's `NewPicture` action, The `Id` is set to 0 and the `GalleryId` set to the `id` parameter.
In the View, I have a form that contains multiple inputs for `PictureSaveViewModel`.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.GalleryId)
```

Here are two hidden inputs for `Id` and `GalleryId` for the specified model.I expect that the hidden filed `Id`'s value to be 0 and `GalleryId`'s value to be the `id` of the parameter. But when I call the action like this `/Gallery/NewPicture/82`, both hidden fields value is `82`

```
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Id must be a number." data-val-required="The Id field is required." id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="82">
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field GalleryId must be a number." data-val-required="The GalleryId field is required." id="GalleryId" name="GalleryId" type="hidden" value="82">
```

I don't know this is happening. I event tried to `@Html.Hidden("Id" ,@Model.Id)`, but still same result.
Other input fiels like `title, description, ....` are working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your request, you get the Id parameter. So when you pass the model with that filed name it will automatically used the request id data. So please try the below code, change the id parameter to tid

```
 public ActionResult NewPicture(int tid)

    {
        var response = service.Get(tid);
        if (!response.Succeed)
           return Error(response.MainError.ErrorType);
        return ManagementView("/Gallery/EditPicture.cshtml", new PictureSaveViewModel() { Id = 0, GalleryId = tid });
    }
```